# How do I extract a word between pipes using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a parser and I need to extract words that are between double pipes using php

For example I want to extract the 'ipsum' from the string below

```
Lorem ||ipsum|| blah
```

If there are multiple words between double pipes, they should be extracted as well

**Clarification**

When I say multiple words I don't mean this: ||word another word||

I mean this

```
||Word1|| blah blah (newline)
blah ||Word2||
```

**Clarification part 2**

```
the ||quick|| brown fox ||jumps|| over the lazy ||dog||
```

What should be extracted should be the words 'quick', 'jumps' and 'dog'

Sorry for the confusion... There probably are some right answers below, I'll pick one once I confirm it tomorrow at work :)

Comment: is regex going to accomplish this issue more effectively than normal splits on || could?

Comment: The text is not pipe separated, it's a multiline file that might contain multiple special words that are between double pipes. Exploding it could work but if there is a one line solution instead of looping through the file to make sure the word isn't between pipes in different lines I'd prefer it

Comment: I so confused by what your actually looking for :S and the example does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/\|\|(.*)\|\|/', $str, $matches) === 1){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Or if there are multiple `||`, try this:

```
if(preg_match_all('/\|\|(.*?)\|\|/', $str, $matches) !== FALSE){
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: Difference between this and my expression is that this will allow `|` inside of the `||word||` structure, but it will also mess up on a string such as this one: `it will ||fail|| right ||here||. trust me`. See: http://regex101.com/r/kZ0tO6

Comment: @Lindrian: That depends what the OP wants.  My regex will extract `fail|| right ||here`.

Comment: Correct. I assumed he did _not_ want that, but who knows. Now he has both solutions to pick from :)!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... Loss of sleep will do that :/ What I want is from the string 'it will ||fail|| right ||here||. trust me extract the words 'fail' and 'here'

Comment: @Rocket thank you! I'll accept your answer once I confirm it tomorrow since I cannot figure it out right now :)

Answer (score 4):

What about a simple

```
$array = explode('||', $string);
```

After that, you probably want to trim the array values using trim().

See also http://www.php.net/explode and http://www.php.net/trim

Comment: Note that only odd-number indices in the resulting array should be counted as "between pipes".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex solution: http://regex101.com/r/vE9pY9

```
 /\Q||\E[^|]+\Q||\E/
```

This will not accept pipes to be a part of the word though. If that is a requirement the regex has to be remade.

Comment: `\Q` is the start of a 'quote', `\E` (optional) ends the previously started quote block. As you can see in the explanation at regex101.com, the characters `||` inside `\Q\E` are treated literally. It is not too common, but I use it when I have to escape several characters. Increases readability a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your looking for:

```
\|\|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|\|
```

This should satisfy your example:

```
||Word1|| blah blah (newline)
blah ||Word2||
```

Of picking Word1 and Word2 out.

You will need to strip off the `||` on either side.

There is a way to use regex to strip the `||` out as well but KISS. It is easier to read and easier to, in general, strip this stuff out later. So you have a simple regex with a simple trim.

Hope it helps,